# Passport deserialize calls twice per each request

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

When I open any url in my node js + passport app I have 2 request for database (deserialze method call probably).

**My log:**

```
NEW QUERY____________________
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$1
[ '1' ]
GET / 200 248ms - 829b
NEW QUERY____________________
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$1
[ '1' ]
GET /stylesheets/style.css 404 3ms
```

**Deserializtation method and middleware:**

```
app.configure(function() {
    // all environments
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: "thisismysecretkey",
        store: new RedisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: redisClient })
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
});



passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    user.get(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

It seems like this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213484/passport-deserializeuser-executing-a-db-sequelize-command-for-each-http-reques) but it is not working for me.

**I have working authentication with passport js it looks a bit scared:**

```
exports.authenticate = function (req, res) {
var form = new multiparty.Form();

form.parse(req, function(err, fields) {
    var userEmail = fields.email[0];
    var userPassword = fields.password[0];
    if (err) throw err;
    userProvider.isBlockedEmail(userEmail, function(err, blocked) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (blocked) {
            res.send({error: true, description: 'you did too much attempts'});
        } else {
            userProvider.authenticate(userEmail,  userPassword, function (err, user) {
                if (err) throw err;
                else if (user === undefined) res.send({error: true, description: 'wrong login or password'});
                else if (user) {
                    req.login(user, function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        else if (user.banned === true) res.send({error: true, description: 'access denied'});
                        else {
                            userProvider.resetAttemptsCounter(userEmail, function(err) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                res.send(req.user);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    userProvider.checkAndBlock(userEmail, function(err, isBlocked, descriptions) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        if (isBlocked) {
                            res.send({error: true, description: descriptions});
                        } else {
                            userProvider.increaseAttemptsCounter(userEmail, function(err) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                res.send({error: true, description: 'wrong login or password'});
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

};

***Please help me to avoid this overhead.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's a similar issue:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.favicon()); <---- !!
app.use(app.router);
```

This means that the Passport middlewares will be called for each request to `/favicon.ico` (which is pretty much for every page).

You should re-order it so that `express.favicon` is called *before* the Passport middlewares:

```
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: **GET /stylesheets/style.css 404 3ms** seems like I am linking css but I am not.

Comment: @SlowHarry it has to come from *somewhere* :)

Comment: I linked it but it, however there is again request(now one for any request).

Comment: @SlowHarry I don't think you can avoid that, Passport doesn't know which routes require deserialization and which routes don't.

Comment: I fix it just by switching off `passport.session()`, using `req.session.user` instead of using `req.user`