# ExpressJs Passportjs de-serializes user object for every request to a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I have a `ExpressJS` app that is using `Passportjs` to authenticate with Facebook and everything is working as expected exception for one issue.

I have `vehicle.js` under `/routes/` which contains some routes (router.gets and router.posts) that need authentication and some that don't. If user is logged in then every request handled by `vehicle.js` causes User de-serialization which is a `Mongoose` lookup. **How can I avoid these unnecessary `Mongoose` lookups when request is made to a `router.get` and/or `router.post` that do not need authentication?**

I have already looked up this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213484/passport-deserializeuser-executing-a-db-sequelize-command-for-each-http-reques) and it does not address my problem (I have declared static resources above passport, so they are not authenticated).

`Passport` configs in `app.js` are shown below:

```
// Configuring Passport
var passport = require('passport');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

app.use(expressSession({secret: 'thisIsSecret'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Using the flash middleware provided by connect-flash to store messages in session
// and displaying in templates
var flash = require('connect-flash');
app.use(flash());

// Initialize Passport
var initPassport = require('./passport/init');
initPassport(passport);

//passing passport object could be the reason why all requested that are 
//mapped in vehicle cause user de-serialization. Not sure if there is any
//alternative approach than following line that passes passport??
var vehicle = require('./routes/vehicle')(passport);
```

The following isAuthenticated is in `vehicle.js`

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
    // if the user is not authenticated then redirect him to the login page
    res.redirect('/vehicle/api/login');
}
```

Followed by a series of `routes` that handle `logging in`, `logging out`, as well as some actions on `vehicle`.

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
  router.get('/api/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('vehicle/login', { message: req.flash('message') });
  });
  router.post('/api/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
    successRedirect: '/vehicle/api/list/mine',
    failureRedirect: '/vehicle/api/list',
    failureFlash : true
  }));
  ...
  ...
  ...
  router.post('/api/upload', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
    //this route needs to  be authenticated, so it works fine, 
    //deserialization done, mongoose lookup, no problem
  }); 
  router.get('/api/image/:vehicleId/:filename', function(req,res) {
    //this route does not need authentication, but causes User 
    //de-serialization and Mongoose lookup
  }); 
 return router;
}
```

Is it because of the following line that every request to `vehicle.js` causes User de-serialization when a user is logged in?

```
var vehicle = require('./routes/vehicle')(passport);
```

One way to avoid such unnecessary de-serialization would be to separate routes that do not need authentication from `vehicle.js` to a different file and do not pass that passport object to that file (as it is passed to `vehicle.js` in `app.js`). I don't know if that is the correct way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the passport middleware inside a custom middleware that only invokes it for your specified routes. So Instead of:

```
app.use(passport.session());
```

you could:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  if(req.url.match('api/image'))
    next(); // do not invoke passport
  else
    passport.session()(req, res, next)
    // same as doing == app.use(passport.session())
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I have a question though, if not mistaken the above if condition is executed for every request. Right? Not sure what is the cost of that if condition. Also, do you think it is efficient to use if condition or apply passport.session() to specific route (after separating secure/non-secure routes)?

Comment: @Raf cost of adding a middleware is practically nothing. [I'm measuring ~0.06ms](http://i.imgur.com/6h3gx2k.png). It'd probably be less in production. So to me, efficiency-wise it wouldn't matter much. I would probably base the choice on other factors, like whatever code makes more sense to reason about.

Comment: @Raf In addition to what laggingreflex mentioned, I also tweaked the passport deserialize function to store a temporary (like 10-20 seconds) in-memory copy of the "deserialized" user value. Reason is many a times the user navigates through pages quickly or a page might have multiple requests made. In such cases, I lookup mongodb once and for the next 20 seconds or so any additional requests are handled from in-memory rather hitting mongodb/db-server. This made my webpage responses quite a bit faster.

Comment: @user3658423 is there any way I can have a look at the tweaked version of the passport's deserialized function? You could add it as an answer, I would definitely give you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `passport.session()` middleware, deserialize will happen for every route: 
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/33075756a626999c6e2efc872b055e45ae434053/lib/strategies/session.js#L53-L69

The solution would be to add it only to ones which use passport.

Comment: What do you mean by **The solution would be to add it only to ones which use passport**?